# NetBeans not working right

Tags: java, netbeans, output, runtime

I am running this code in NetBeans by pressing the green arrow which says Run Project. But I get no output. Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong I'm new to the IDE.

```
package nurel;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Nurel {

    public String[] chars = new String[90];
    public String var;
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    public void charsdef(){
        chars[0] = "a";
        chars[1] = "b";
        chars[2] = "c";
        chars[3] = "d";
        chars[4] = "e";
        chars[5] = "f";
        chars[6] = "g";
        chars[7] = "h";
        chars[8] = "i";
        chars[9] = "g";
        chars[10] = "k";
        chars[11] = "l";
        chars[12] = "m";
        chars[13] = "n";
        chars[14] = "o";
        chars[15] = "p";
        chars[16] = "q";
        chars[17] = "r";
        chars[18] = "s";
        chars[19] = "w";
        chars[20] = "x";
        chars[21] = "y";
        chars[22] = "z";
        chars[23] = "v";
        chars[24] = "t";
        chars[25] = "j";
        chars[26] = "u";
        chars[27] = "0";
        chars[28] = "1";
        chars[29] = "2";
        chars[30] = "3";
        chars[31] = "4";
        chars[32] = "5";
        chars[33] = "6";
        chars[34] = "7";
        chars[35] = "8";
        chars[36] = "9";
        chars[37] = "A";
        chars[38] = "B";
        chars[39] = "C";
        chars[40] = "D";
        chars[41] = "E";
        chars[42] = "F";
        chars[43] = "G";
        chars[44] = "H";
        chars[45] = "I";
        chars[46] = "G";
        chars[47] = "K";
        chars[48] = "L";
        chars[49] = "M";
        chars[50] = "N";
        chars[51] = "O";
        chars[52] = "P";
        chars[53] = "Q";
        chars[54] = "R";
        chars[55] = "S";
        chars[56] = "W";
        chars[57] = "X";
        chars[58] = "Y";
        chars[59] = "Z";
        chars[60] = "V";
        chars[61] = "T";
        chars[62] = "J";
        chars[63] = "U";
        chars[64] = "`";
        chars[65] = "?";
        chars[66] = ".";
        chars[67] = "!";
        chars[68] = "\"";
        chars[69] = "+";
        chars[70] = "=";
        chars[71] = " ";
        chars[72] = "@";
        chars[73] = "£";
        chars[74] = "$";
        chars[75] = "%";
        chars[76] = "*";
        chars[77] = "|";
        chars[78] = "/";
        chars[79] = "{";
        chars[80] = "}";
        chars[81] = "[";
        chars[82] = "]";
        chars[83] = "\\";
        chars[84] = ";";
        chars[85] = ":";        

    }

    public void attem(){
       String var = input.nextLine();
       boolean k = var.contains(this.chars[84]);
       System.out.println(k);

    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
       Nurel c = new Nurel();
       c.charsdef();
       c.attem();
       System.out.println("try");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you giving the input required when you call `attem()`?

Comment: Are there any error messages? Does it say it ran but its not printing anything?

Comment: It doesn't print anything because it's waiting for input. ``input.nextLine();`` blocks until you provide a text and hit enter. Type it in the console (where you would expect the output).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your program is waiting for an input from the user in the `attem` method. `String var = input.nextLine();` will halt the program until an input is put in. You should enter an input on the console in order to get the results you want.